# Firebase Notification broke server notifications

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have made the switch from GCM to FCM in my android app. But I have not touched the server portion of the code since supposedly I don’t have to. But now, when server sends a notification, my device is no longer seeing it. So did I misunderstand the following?

https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/android-migrate-fcm#update_server_endpoints

> Updating these endpoints is not strictly required, as Google will
>   continue to support the existing GCM endpoints.

**MANIFEST**

```
<!-- for notifications -->
    <!--<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>-->
    <!--<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>-->
    <!--<uses-permission android:name="com.business.myapp.android.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>-->

…

<application …>

…
<!-- START GCM SECTION -->
        <!--<receiver-->
            <!--android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"-->
            <!--android:exported="true"-->
            <!--android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">-->
            <!--<intent-filter>-->
                <!--<action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>-->

                <!--<category android:name="com.business.myapp"/>-->
            <!--</intent-filter>-->
        <!--</receiver>-->

        <service
            android:name=".data.service.notification.BusinessGcmListenerService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service
            android:name=".data.service.notification.BusinessInstanceIDListenerService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service
            android:name=".data.service.notification.RegistrationIntentService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <!-- END GCM SECTION -->
```

Note that when I send notification from the Firebase Console it comes through: if the app is in the foreground, it goes through `onMessageReceived`; otherwise, I just get a notification in status bar. Basically I follow the instructions on the link provided.

Here is onTokenRefresh

```
@Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, RegistrationIntentService.class);
    startService(intent);//intent service to send token to my server
}
```

Comment: So I followed all the instructions on that page. Except the server has not been changed (another team would have to do it); also the note says I don't need to change the server.

Comment: Did you create a new Firebase project as part of this at all? Or was it an upgrade from your existing Google project?

Comment: No new project. I just use my existing project.

Comment: Could you include a snippet of your FCM implementation on the client and the relevant parts of the manifest? The issue may be there.

Comment: I have added the manifest data and some. I just followed the step by step they provide see link https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/android-migrate-fcm#import_your_gcm_project_as_a_firebase_project

Comment: Just to check - GCM sender ID you were using before - does that match the project number value in the google-services.json?

Answer (score 0):

Do you change your json-service.json of on root /app of on application ?