# android GCM migration to Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-endpoints, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have just migrated my project that uses GCM to Firebase, by following [this guide](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/android-migrate-fcm#remove_registration). At the end of the migration guide it mentions that optionally one can replace the Google server endpoints with the ones from Firebase. However, when I try to send messages between devices, they are not delivered.

The only case that works is when I replace my old GOOGLE_API_KEY with the one I got from Firebase but with Google's endpoints!

From what I see in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37470733/firebase-notification-broke-server-notifications) others also face similar issues. Has anyone any hint on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after searching a bit more, I saw that for sending messages via the FCM the server end point should be `fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send`, i.e. append the /send. This is a bit confusing, because in the migration guide the /send is not mentioned, whereas in [this link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/topic-messaging#sending_topic_messages_from_the_server) and [this SO solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37426542/firebase-cloud-messaging-notification-from-java-instead-of-firebase-console) it does.

Unless I am missing something, the migration guide should be updated.